# Show information about several tables on the same view on Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm trying to show a list of question and his respective answers. I store all on 3 different database tables, questions>type of answer>list of possible answers.

This is what I've done on the controller:

```
public function show()
{
    $questions = DB::table('questions')
        ->join('typeAnswers', 'typeAnswers.id', '=', 'questions.answer_id')
        ->join('answers', 'answers.typeAnswers_id', '=', 'typeAnswers.id')
        ->get();

    return view('questions.showquestions', ['questions' => $questions]);
}
```

On the view I use a foreach iteration to show all the questions:

```
@extends('welcome')

@section('content')
    @foreach($questions as $question)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">{{$question->statement}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                {{$question->value}}
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

On the database for testing I just have one question, and the possible answers are Yes or No. But instead of see one question and two possible answers, I get the same question 2 times and each time a one different answer.

Comment: You get the same question twice because such a question has 2 answers. Try to implement this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387696/how-to-concatenate-strings-from-multiple-rows-in-one-column-inner-join-in-one

Comment: Have you considered using `Eloquent`?

Answer (score 0):

Check this query:

```
$questions = DB::table('questions')
->join('typeAnswers', 'typeAnswers.id', '=', 'questions.answer_id')
->join('answers', 'answers.typeAnswers_id', '=', 'typeAnswers.id')
->get();
```

You are joining `questions` table with `typeAnswers` so the result here is some thing like:

```
Q1    A1
Q1    A2
```

And on view the required result is like:

```
Q1    [A1, A2]
```

So that you can show answers under one question. Modify your query accordingly.