# sql query for chess game

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on an online chess game.

In the database, I have created a *user* table, and a table for the *games*.
I used a *participant* table to connect them. This way I could create many *games* for each *user*, and have 2 *players* for each *game*.

As you can see:

[image: Schema View]

The query I need: get a user *Id* and return all the *games* he/she played. Result table will contains *Date*, *moves*, *players* (the row players will show the *username* of each user that played in this *game*).

For example if I have row in userTable:

```
Id:1 UserName:p1
```

After I use the query it will return:

```
Date     | Players | moves
11/11/11   p1vsp2    ...
11/12/12   p1vsp3    ...
11/10/10   p1vsp2    ...
```

Comment: Please show an attempt, and be specific on what the hard part is.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @underscore_d i want to write the query.

Comment: @MIGHTY_FLUFFY ... what query did you try? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service but Q/A forum to help solve earnest attempts that face errors or undesired results.

Comment: Perhaps you need something like SUBSTRING to combine multiple rows into one row. Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21388105/4700922

Answer (score 0):

Though I dont encourage getting code from Stack Overflow here is a start to help you get going.

You have linked all your tables in the above diagram. If you are having troubles with the joins here is a start

```
SELECT .... (insert field names here) FROM User U
```

Next we add the JOINS

```
JOIN Participant p on u.id = p.id
JOIN GAME g on g.idgame = p.id_game
```

Now you will have to put in some criteria to further filter it using a WHERE clause

```
WHERE someField = someValue
```